# Is jhipster only for backend or frontend?

Tags: microservices, jhipster

I am new to java nd jhipster so I have some questions.
Jhipster can generate frontend and backend code in monolithic type but perpose of frontend is only for administrating or for last users? We have to still create application for last users?
Eg. if we want to create blog app and we can create backend for api and frontend for administering by jhipster now for last users who can use blogs we have to create another frontend am I right?

Sorry for my English.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the Last Users as the 'End Users' or the people who will create the blogs?

If yes, I think that there is no need to create another front-end for the blog users.

You could make use of the *jhiHasAnyAuthority directive to switch front end views and processes for the end user.

Unless, you plan to have a completely different view and functionality with the 'Last/End user' blogs.